# Google Sheets: Get max value and corresponding values from other columns in a query function

Tags: google-sheets, filter, datatable

I'm a bit lost with Google Sheets.

***This is just a example with Google Finance to illustrate my problem!***

I use a code like this

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "all" , DATE(2022,6,21), DATE(2022,6,29))
```

to get this table:

[image]

My goal is to get the max value in Column 6 (Volume) with the corresponding values from Column 1(Date) & 3(High). The output has to be in the same cell as the formula (the whole table should never show up).

It should basically look like this:

[image]

I use this code to get the max value from Column 6

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "all" , DATE(2022,6,21), DATE(2022,6,29)),"select Max(Col6) label Max(Col6)''")
```

but I can't find a solution to add the corresponding values from Col1 and Col3 to the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 01**

Paste this formula to get the "desired output", no need for the table either! [Link to the Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cn_EjZkZeM_v-oVCHhPJNy3JH-wqj2zatEytV4-Htic/edit?usp=sharing).

```
=SORTN(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "all" , DATE(2022,6,21), DATE(2022,6,29))," Select Col1,Col3,Col6 ",0),1,,2,0)
```

**Explanation**

1 - [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) the input in this case `GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "all" , DATE(2022,6,21), DATE(2022,6,29))` and set "query" Col1,Col3 and Col6
Date, High and Volume, wiht [headers] set to `0`

2 - [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) the result and set The number of items to return [n] `1` to get the top 1 result including the headers in this case [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) fuction [headers] is set to `0` so [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) returns only one row , and set [sort_column] to `6` "Volume", and [is_ascending] to `0`.

**Option 02**

To output the result with headers.

```
=SORTN(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "all" , DATE(2022,6,21), DATE(2022,6,29))," Select Col1,Col3,Col6 "),2,,2,0)
```

**Explanation**

1 - [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) the input in this case `GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "all" , DATE(2022,6,21), DATE(2022,6,29))` and set "query" Col1,Col3 and Col6
Date, High and Volume.

2 - [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) the result and set The number of items to return [n] `2` to get the top 1 result including the headers, and set [sort_column] to `6` "Volume", and [is_ascending] to `0`.

[image: ُExample]

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "all" , DATE(2022,6,21), DATE(2022,6,29)),
"select Col1, Col3, Max(Col6) group by Col1, Col3 order by Max(Col6) desc limit 1 label Max(Col6) ''",0)
```

Comment: An explanation might be helpful. You are writing an answer not only for the person who asked the question, but also for future visitors to this answer.